# cannot read settings from /etc/security/limits.conf: Permission denied

Tags: linux, centos

I modified the file /etc/security/limits.conf in the purpose of increasing resource limits. But it led to error: “Error in service module”. So I restored /etc/security/limits.conf, but new error arose：“cannot read settings from /etc/security/limits.conf: Permission denied” . And I tried chmod , no mode works. 
[image: The screen shot]
And I have pam config for login like this:
[image: pam config]

It really makes me mad . Dose anyone can help me ???!!!  Orz

My system is Centos7, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You should verify the permissions all the way to the file:

```
dr-xr-xr-x 25 root root  4096 Jan  7  2016 /
drwxr-xr-x 95 root root 12288 Sep  1 13:09 /etc
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root  4096 Jul 28 11:37 /etc/security
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2422 Jul 28 11:37 /etc/security/limits.conf
```

If you're running SELinux in enforcing mode then you should also run

```
restorecon /etc/security/limits.conf
```

to ensure the file has the right security context.

```
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. I checked the permissions, and ran the "restorecon /etc/security/limits.conf". The system no longer keep me out finally. I will try to learn further about "SELinux in enforcing mode". Thank you again, you saved from crazy mad .